# Can't submit input matrix name

Tags: php, html

I have table like this:

```
<tr>
<td style="width:5% !important;"><input type="text" style="width:50%" name="CostingSheet[CostingSheetCredits[][pax_adult]]" value="1"></td>
<td style="width:5% !important;"><input type="text" style="width:50%" name="CostingSheet[CostingSheetCredits[][pax_inf]]" value=""></td>
</tr>
```

and when I submit it I get array like this:

```
["CostingSheetCredits["]=>
    ["pax_adult"]=> "2"
    ["pax_inf"]=> ""
```

and I would like to get something like this:

```
["CostingSheetCredits]=>
 [0] =>
    ["pax_adult"]=> "2"
    ["pax_inf"]=> ""
```

What am I doing wrong? This bugs me for few days already. Thanks everyone for your answers and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a grouping name like this:

```
<input type="text" style="width:50%" name="CostingSheet[CostingSheetCredits][0][pax_adult]" value="1">
<input type="text" style="width:50%" name="CostingSheet[CostingSheetCredits][0][pax_inf]" value="2">
```

So that they will be considered on the same nest:

```
CostingSheet[CostingSheetCredits][0][pax_adult]
CostingSheet[CostingSheetCredits][0][pax_inf]
                                  ^ same row index
```

Answer (score 0):

just pass the 0 or change the name from

```
CostingSheet[CostingSheetCredits[][pax_adult]]
```

to

```
CostingSheet[CostingSheetCredits][0][pax_adult]
```

you need to make the change for both the fields.

Comment: I tried. Than I get 
`["CostingSheetCredits[0"]=>
    ["pax_adult"]=> "2"
    ["pax_inf"]=> ""`